# script gets a bug when I record Shell output

Tags: linux, shell

I wanted to know how to record all the input and output of my terminal.

Of course, I can use the `script` command but I am going to record every user's input and output. So I put script into file: `.barhrc` for every user's home directory.
Just like this:
`script -a -f -q $RECORDFILE`

But I met a bug when other program or Shell script executed `source ~/.bashrc`. Because `source ~/.bashrc` go into a new shell environment，so it stops my script from going any further util I use the exit command and stop the recording.

I'm sorry for my poor English.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a variable and also check that input is a TTY:

```
if [[ -z "$RECORDING" && -t 0 ]]
then
  RECORDING="YES" exec script -afq "$RECORDFILE"
fi
```

- The variable ensures that you will not start recording in a session that is already being recorded.
- Checking that input is a terminal ensures that any script running from `cron` or similar will not try to start recording, even if such a script runs `source ~/.bashrc` to try to set up some variables.

You should also see whether `~/.bash_profile` is a better place to start recording. This file runs only on login, and scripts usually don't try to `source` it. However, some terminal emulators will not start up with login shells, so they may not start recording.